# How to call a static function in add_action() inside another static function?

Tags: actions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

In my plugin, I would like to load css only when the front-end current page is using one of my plugin shortcodes.

All my shortcodes are classes extending Shortcode class. Shortcode class helps me to automate the callback function.

**Shortcode abstract class**

```
namespace PluginFoo\Shortcodes;


abstract class Shortcode {

    public $tag;
    public $attrs;
    public $function;

    public function __construct($tag) {
        $this->attrs = array();
        $this->tag = $tag;
        $this->function = static::className().'::getCallBack';

        add_shortcode( $this->tag, $this->function );

    }

    abstract public static function className();

    abstract public static function getCallBack( $attrs ); 
}
```

**FooShortcode class**

```
namespace PluginFoo\Shortcodes;

class FooShortcode extends Shortcode {

    public static function getCallBack( $attrs = null ){

        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'set_bootstrap' ) ); // <-- Here - function set_bootstrap not called !

        $output = '';

        ob_start();

        //HTML Template
         include_once 'shortcode-view.php';

        $output .= ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $output;

    }

    public static function set_bootstrap() {
         wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapstyle', PLUGIN_DIR_URL . 'css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    }

    public static function className(){
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

How can I call correcty the static function set_bootstrap() in add_action() inside an another static function ?

Comment: what do you mean by "Does not work" ? give more details

Comment: the function set_bootstrap() is not called.

Comment: have you activated WP_DEBUG ? https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: Yes, of course. I have got any error in the debug.log file.

Comment: Do you think, it's not called because the action 'wp_enqueue_scripts' was run before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is called statically you need to use `get_called_class()` like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array( get_called_class(), 'set_bootstrap' ) );
```

since `$this` is not available. This also works if the class is extended.

Answer (score 1):

you can use classname::class
for example:

```
add_shortcodes(callback::class, 'callbackmethod');
```